# Windows11 ssh-agent does not remember passphrase

Tags: ssh, windows-11, openssh, ssh-agent, private-key

I am facing the issue that my running ssh-agent is not remembering my private key passphrase. It keeps prompting to enter it, each time I open an SSH session. I cannot figure out why and hope somebody else can offer support.

- OS Name: Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
- OS Version: 10.0.22621 N/A Build 22621
- SSH: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3

My .ssh dir contain the keys and a config file. All files have the correct owner/permissions:
**PS C:\Users\lmole.ssh> ls ~/.ssh**

```
    Directory: C:\Users\lmole\.ssh


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         28-3-2023     08:36           1631 config
-a----         24-2-2022     13:01           1743 id_rsa
-a----         27-3-2023     08:22           3457 known_hosts
-a----         24-2-2022     13:20           1743 openssh1.key
-a----         24-2-2022     13:01           1743 openssh2.key
```

The config file explicity states to remember the password
**~/.ssh/config**

```
# Personal key for NAS
Host nas
    HostName 192.168.0.150
    Port 22
    User lucas
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile C:\Users\lmole\.ssh\openssh2.key
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

My agent is listing the keys **PS G:> ssh-add -l**

```
2048 SHA256:xxxxxjwUDVgN6hWv6G0D00MmMOjww C:\Users\lmole\.ssh\openssh1.key (RSA)
2048 SHA256:xxxxxBSIujD4VAVGICODc1yfMv5cFtdQ/w C:\Users\lmole\.ssh\openssh2.key (RSA)
```

But still it continues to ask for the password:
**PS C:\Users\lmole.ssh> ssh -v nas**

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\lmole/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\lmole/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: C:\\Users\\lmole/.ssh/config line 35: Applying options for nas
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.150 [192.168.0.150] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\lmole\\.ssh\\openssh2.key type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\lmole\\.ssh\\openssh2.key-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.150:22 as 'lucas'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\lmole/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:slphIsy0RzP60Ewpt2tpXexiXgiS9YH0blskOgX4/Ns
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\lmole/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '192.168.0.150' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\lmole/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\lmole\\.ssh\\openssh2.key  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\lmole\\.ssh\\openssh2.key
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\lmole\.ssh\openssh2.key':
```

After entering my password:

```
debug1: identity added to agent: C:\\Users\\lmole\\.ssh\\openssh2.key
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.0.150 ([192.168.0.150]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching C:\\Users\\lmole/.ssh/known_hosts for 192.168.0.150 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching C:\\Users\\lmole/.ssh/known_hosts2 for 192.168.0.150 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file C:\\Users\\lmole/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug1: Remote: /home/lucas/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
Linux nas.xxx.xxx 5.10.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.162-1 (2023-01-21) x86_64
```

These are the steps I follow. The password is not stored. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by replacing the files in "c:\program files\openssh" with the files from a Windows 10 installation. Windows 10 uses ssh 8.1p1 while Windows 11 uses 9.2.p1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).